# Помогите проверить запятые в предложении с обстоятельствами и уточнениями?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

1. Вася родился, вполне здоровым ребенком, 3 мая 1979 года, во вторник, в половине первого ночи, в  городе Энске.
2. Вася родился в городе  Энске, вполне здоровым ребенком, 3 мая 1979 года.

Запятые правильно расставлены ? И почему правильно или неправильно? 
 Числительные правильно написаны ? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вася родился вполне здоровым ребенком 3 мая 1979 года, во вторник, в половине первого ночи, в городе Энске. Слова "вполне здоровым ребенком" нет необходимости обособлять, так как это обычные члены предложения. "Во вторник, в половине первого ночи" - обособляем уточняющие обстоятельства времени при наличии уточняемого "3 мая 1979 года". Во втором предложении обособлять нечего, так как все слова являются разными членами предложения